# Django - returning German date with strftime

Tags: python, django, date, strftime

I have this code:

```
 date = program.last_registration_date.strftime('%d %B %Y, %H:%M')
```

`program` is my model and `last_registration_date` is a normal value from a `DateTimeField`

Now my problem is that date returns an English date, which I don't want. In my `default.py` I've set my TIME_ZONE correctly ('Europe/Berlin'), my LANGUAGE_CODE ('de') and ofc USE_L1ON is set on True. But it still not German.

I tried to import locale and use a setlocale after my imports, but that also won't work (just shows me an error that locale is an unsupported setting).

So, anyone can help me how to turn this date German?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out and just removed the `strftime` to use:

```
 date = date_format(program.last_registration_date)
```

Which worked without a problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have proper configuration of `settings` and `formats` in Django project. Structure of example project:

```
.
|-- README.md
|-- demo.db
|-- demo_time_set
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- demo.db
|   |-- formats
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- en
|   |       |-- __init__.py
|   |       `-- formats.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
|-- manage.py
|-- requirments.txt
`-- some_app
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- admin.py
    `-- models.py
```

You can define it for multiple languages just by providing directory with appropriate name and formats.py inside.
The example content of `formats.py` where all the MAGIC happens can look as follows:

```
# HERE FORMATING AS shown in:
# LIST: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date
DATE_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y'
TIME_FORMAT = 'H:i'
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y H:i'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 1

# BUT here use the Python strftime format syntax,
# LIST: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d-%m-%Y',     # '21-03-2014'
)
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%H:%M:%S',     # '17:59:59'
    '%H:%M',        # '17:59'
)
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M',     # '21-03-2014 17:59'
)

DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = u'.'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = u','
NUMBER_GROUPING = 3
```

**Please notice two links in the comments, which will guide you to lists of proper configurations, which ARE DIFFERENT for DIFFERENT parts!**

In your `settings.py` just add:

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = 'demo_time_set.formats'
```

[GITHUB] Here is a full working example: https://github.com/andilab/demo_time_set

Comment: Thanks for that, really appreciate your effort, but I found an easier solution for myself :)